# Change the path of the chunk-vendors.js in Vue.js CLI (webpack config)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, configuration, command-line-interface

I have the following `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
filenameHashing: false,
productionSourceMap: false,
outputDir: '../vuejs/',
configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js'
    }
},
pages: {
    feature1: {
        entry: 'src/f1.js',
        template: 'public/feature.html',
        filename: 'index1.html',
        title: 'Feature 1',
        chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'feature1']
    },
    feature2: {
        entry: 'src/f2.js',
        template: 'public/feature.html',
        filename: 'index2.html',
        title: 'Feature 2',
        chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'feature2']
    }
} 
}
```

On `npm run build` it generates:

```
index1.html 
index2.html 
feature1.js 
feature2.js 
js/chunk-vendors.js
```

in the dist folder (`../vuejs/`)

How could I change the configuration so the file `chunk-vendors.js` would be placed in the root folder (where `feature1.js` and `feature2.js` are).

P.S. : (Extra question) I actually do not need the html files, as I embed the vue.js `*.js` into an existing application. Can I suppress the generation of the html files?

Comment: Have you looked at https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/ . You should be able to specify another property path

Comment: @CodeSurvivor hi - thanks for the tip. I use the outputDir as suggested from the vue-cli-service build command.
If one tries to use output.path one gets : Configuration Error: Avoid modifying webpack output.path directly. Use the "outputDir" option instead.

And as described I get 2 of the files feature1 and feature2 in the right place. Only the chunk-vendors.js go into the ./js/ folder ...

Comment: Hi @AlexanderMihailov — any success with this? I have the same problem, `outputDir` is building the main app file where I want but `chunk-vendors` is not. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can define an explicit [`chunkFilename`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputchunkfilename); e.g:

```js
module.exports = {
  outputDir: 'my/custom/build/path/',
  configureWebpack: (config) => {
    config.output.filename = '[name].[hash:8].js';
    config.output.chunkFilename = '[name].[hash:8].js';
  }
}
```

Which should generate something like:

```
my/custom/build/path/app.216ad62b.js
my/custom/build/path/app.216ad62b.js.map
my/custom/build/path/chunk-vendors.6f85144f.js
my/custom/build/path/chunk-vendors.6f85144f.js.map
```

Hope this helps :)